# Creating a multidimensional array and accessing fields

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been running around in circles over this for days ... please help.

I am trying to create a multidimensional array based on the number of files in a directory and the parsed filename ...

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
     echo "$file[0] $file[1]  <br>\n" ;  #file[0]=Unix timestamp; file[1]=filename
     $pn = explode('.', $file[1]);
     $ndt = explode('_',array_shift($pn)) ;
         foreach ($ndt as $arndt) {
         $items[$arndt] = $ndt ; //this part does not work
         echo "$ndt[0] $ndt[1] $ndt[2] $ndt[3] $ndt[4]" ;
     }
    print_r($items[$arndt]) ;
```

}

The output of my array is this:

Array ( [0] => OLPH [1] => Barbecue [2] => 03132013 [3] => 11am [4] => 2pm )

Note: I just have 1 file in the directory for testing purposes, but there will be more, hence the need for a multidimensional array ...

I then try to access the array in my html using this:

```
<h4><a href="#"><?php echo "$items[$arndt]. $ndt[1]" ?></a></h4>
```

.... naturally, this output does not print the results that I want .... For every file[1] I want to be able to print $arndt[] and access it using $items[][] notation.... however it just prints Array[]Array[] .... Please help ?

Thanks in advance,

Carlos

Comment: change this line  foreach ($ndt as $arndt)  to foreach ($ndt as $arndt => $v)   and $items[$arndt] = $ndt ; to $items[] = $v ;      also change this line echo "$ndt[0] $ndt[1] $ndt[2] $ndt[3] $ndt[4]" ; to echo "$v[0] $v[1] $v[2] $v[3] $v[4]" ;

Comment: I made the proposed changes:

Comment: $files = array("OLPH_Barbecue_03132013_11am_2pm.pdf") ;

foreach ($files as $file) {
         echo "$file[0] $file[1]  <br>\n" ;  #file[0]=Unix timestamp; file[1]=filename
   $pn = explode('.', $file[1]);
   $ndt = explode('_',array_shift($pn)) ;
   foreach ($ndt as $arndt => $v)
   $items[] = $v ;
   echo "$v[0] $v[1] $v[2] $v[3] $v[4]" ;
   }

Comment: this prints "O L 
L " .... I want it to print "OLPH" "Barbecue" , etc ....

Answer (score 0):

echoing/printing an array in string context just gives you `Array`. If you're dealing with multi-dimensional arrays, each dimension has to have its own loop to print out its contents.

e.g.

```
$arr1d = array('foo' => 'bar'); // 1D array
echo $arr1d; // outputs "Array"

$arr2d = array('foo' => array('bar' => 'baz')); // 2D array
echo $arr2d; // outputs 'Array';
echo $arr2d['foo']; // outputs 'Array'
echo $arr2d['foo']['bar']; // outputs 'baz'

foreach($arr2d as $key1 => $val1) {
    echo $val1; // outputs 'Array';
    foreach($val1 as $key2 => $val2) {
        echo $val; // outputs 'Baz'
    }
}
```

Comment: What ?!! I just asked the question ... you guys are fast !! Thanks !  Will try it when I get home.

Comment: The issue is I am not sure what will be the values of the array .... The array likely will be 4 by 5 , but I am not sure .... would I need an array iterator to do this ? Can I do $arr4d = array('$files[1]' => array('$ndt[0]' => '$ndt[1]', ...)); // 4D array .... Is there an easier way to reference individual values without traversing a loop first ?  Thanks again.